# Why is asort in awk messing up one of the records in my array?

Tags: awk, gnu

I'm working on a homework assignment and this is my first experience with using awk. I'm trying to sort an array in descending order, and I seem to have accomplished that... mostly. The output is supposed to show a person's name, position, and sales total from a database file. It works fine unsorted, but when I use asort, the name and position for one of the people (Davy Jones, whose record should be in the middle) are removed, and the format is messed up. Here is my code:

```
BEGIN {
    printf("%4s  %22s  %15s\n", "Name", "Position", "Sales Amount");
    printf("=============================================\n");
    FS = ":";
}

/^[0-9]*:[a-z]*:[A-Z || a-z || -]*:[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/ {
    productPRICEar[pprice_key++] = $4;
}

/^[0-9]*:[A-Z || a-z]*:[A-Z || a-z]*$/ {
    associateNUMar[anum_key++] = $1;
    associateNAMEar[aname_key++] = $2;
    associatePOSar[apos_key++] = $3;
}

/^[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*:[0-9]*$/ {
    transactionIDar[tID_key++] = $1;
    productIDar[pID_key++] = $2;
    quantityar[quant_key++] = $3;
    associateIDar[aID_key++] = $5;
}

END {
    # Create an empty array value for each associate
    for (key in associateNUMar) {
        associate_total[key] = 0; # Stores the total sales made by the associate
    }

    # For each transaction
    for(transaction in transactionIDar) {
        # Declare variables
        belongs_to = associateIDar[transaction]; # Who the transaction belongs to
        product_id = productIDar[transaction]; # ID of the product sold in the transaction
        quantity_sold = quantityar[transaction]; # Quantity of the product sold in the transaction
        transaction_total = productPRICEar[product_id-1] * quantity_sold; # Total revenue from the transaction.

        # For each associate
        for (associate in associateNUMar) {
            # If this is the associate the current transaction belongs to
            if (associateNUMar[associate] == belongs_to) {
                current_total = associate_total[associate]; # Get the associate's current sales total
                associate_total[associate] = current_total + transaction_total; # Add the transaction total to the associate's sales total
            }
        }
    }
    print "\nUnsorted\n=============================================";
    # For each associate's sales total
    for(key2 in associate_total) {
        # Retrieve the associate's records
        associate_name = associateNAMEar[key2]; # Associate's name
        associate_position = associatePOSar[key2]; # Associate's position
        associate_salestotal = associate_total[key2]; # Associate's sales total

        printf("%-18s  %-13s  %10.2f\n", associate_name, associate_position, associate_salestotal);
    }


    n = asort(associate_total);
    print "\nSorted\n=============================================";
    # For each associate's sales total
    for (key2=n; key2>=1; key2--) {
        # Retrieve the associate's records
        associate_name = associateNAMEar[key2]; # Associate's name
        associate_position = associatePOSar[key2]; # Associate's position
        associate_salestotal = associate_total[key2]; # Associate's sales total

        printf("%-18s  %-13s  %10.2f\n", associate_name, associate_position, associate_salestotal);
    }
}
```

This is the database:

```
1:software:Word Processor:55.00
2:software:Bad Wolf Video Game:19.99
3:software:Return to Gallifrey Video Game:59.99
4:vehicle:TARDIS:999999.99
5:hardware:sonic screwdriver:9999.99
6:merchandise:company t-shirt:20.00

1:Davy Jones:Security
2:Ricky Davis:Developer
3:Samantha Smith:Salesperson
4:Matt Smith:Doctor
5:David Tennant:Doctor
6:Buckminster Fuller:Engineer
7:Clara Oswald:Nurse
8:Amelia Pond:Nurse

1:1:1:01/02/2015:2
2:2:1:02/04/2017:2
3:3:1:03/06/2018:5
4:4:1:11/05/2018:5
5:1:1:01/12/2018:2
6:2:2:02/11/2018:2
7:3:1:05/13/2018:6
8:6:3:06/24/2018:1
9:5:1:02/02/2016:5
10:1:1:05/01/2017:5
11:2:1:11/05/2018:5
12:3:1:12/06/2018:5
13:2:1:02/12/2018:5
14:1:1:10/16/2018:5
15:6:4:05/18/2018:3
16:5:1:06/28/2018:6
17:1:1:07/30/2018:5
18:2:1:08/04/2018:7
19:3:1:09/07/2018:5
20:6:1:10/17/2018:4
21:6:1:10/17/2018:8
22:2:1:08/04/2018:7
23:3:1:09/07/2018:5
```

The following is my output. It shows the unsorted and sorted versions. The sorted version is obviously messed up.

```
Name                Position     Sales Amount
=============================================

Unsorted
=============================================
Davy Jones          Security            60.00
Ricky Davis         Developer          169.97
Samantha Smith      Salesperson         80.00
Matt Smith          Doctor              20.00
David Tennant       Doctor         1010444.92
Buckminster Fuller  Engineer         10059.98
Clara Oswald        Nurse               39.98
Amelia Pond         Nurse               20.00

Sorted
=============================================
                                   1010444.92
Amelia Pond         Nurse            10059.98
Clara Oswald        Nurse              169.97
Buckminster Fuller  Engineer            80.00
David Tennant       Doctor              60.00
Matt Smith          Doctor              39.98
Samantha Smith      Salesperson         20.00
Ricky Davis         Developer           20.00
```

This is the logic for the program:

```
1. Products - each product record has the following fields
    1. Product id - an integer uniquely identifying a product
    2. Product category - a string describing the category of the product
    3. Description - a string describing the product
    4. Price - floating point number with 2 significant digits - how much does this product cost?

2. Associates - each record for an associate will have the following fields:
    1. Associate id - an integer uniquely idenfitying the associate
    2. Name - a string containing the name of the associate
    3. Position - a string describing the job position of the associate

3. Sales - each record for a sale will have the following fields
    1. Transaction id - integer uniquely identifying the transaction
    2. Product id - the product id of the product sold in this transaction
    3. Quantity - integer quantifying how many of the specified product were sold
    4. Date - date of the transaction in the format mm/dd/yyyy
    5. Associate id - the associate id of the associate that made this sale
```

I'm not sure why asort is doing this, and I'm completely stuck. Please let me know what the problem is so I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `asort` function rewrites the indices of the array. For instance, if we have an array like this:

```
a["foo"] = "world"
a[9] = "there"
a[3.5] = "hello"
```

then after the sort it looks like this:

```
a[1] = "hello"
a[2] = "there"
a[3] = "world"
```

notice that our original indices have been clobbered. `"world"` is no longer under the key `"foo"`, and so on.

Your first loop iterates over the original keys in `associate_total`. These are then clobbered by `asort`, replaced by the natural numbers from 1 to n. The second loop now iterates over these natural numbers, numerically. It looks as if the original keys didn't consist of the set of natural numbers from 1 to n.

For instance, if the original keys were from 0 to n-1 it means that we no longer have access to the item 0. The new `associate_total` array contains the value n, which doesn't map to any item in the other arrays.

Thus we can reproduce a problem similar to yours using this program:

```
BEGIN {
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     key[i];

   color[0] = "red"
   color[1] = "green"
   color[2] = "blue"


   for (i in key)
     print i, color[i]

   print "---"

   asort(key)

   for (i in key)
     print i, color[i]
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f asort.awk 
0 red
1 green
2 blue
---
1 green
2 blue
3
```

Oops, where is `red` after the `asort`?

My program includes the key values in the output, and that highlights the source of the problem; it's obvious that the set of keys has changed. You might want to print the keys in your program also until it's debugged.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out a fix for this. Would I be able to create an empty value at index 0 and start the actual array at 1, then?

Comment: @triglav Awk arrays are associative; they can have whatever keys you want. See my first example, where the keys are `"foo"`, 9, and 3.5.  There is no need to include an index 0; just start at 1.